# Resetting an enabled button after a file has been selected from listView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have written a program in C# using a windows form in Visual Studio 2017. It displays in splitContainer a treeView displaying directory with subdirectories on the left panel and a listView showing the files in selected directory on the right. I made a button (deleteFiles) which I initially set the Enabled property to False. I want it to be not enabled until the user selects file from the listView and then resets to not enabled until the next file is selected. Here is my code:

```
 private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (listView1.SelectedItems != null)
        {
            bntDeleteFile.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            bntDeleteFile.Enabled = false;
        }
     }
```

When I run the program the button becomes enabled after I select a file, but it remains enabled afterwards even if no files are selected. How do I have the button reset to the not enabled state until the next file is selected.

Comment: The flow is: select a file -> enable the button -> deletes the file -> disable the button (and this part is what is wrong). Right?

Comment: If the selected index is -1, disable the button.

Comment: Basically I also want it to be disabled if I unselect a file by selecting a directory on the treeView side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Order of Events in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.load?view=netframework-4.7.1)

For Windows Forms I recommend setting the control in the form load event.  Setting the button enable to false will disable the button prior to the user seeing the form:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    bntDeleteFile.Enabled = false;
}
```

Also do you have a button click event that disables the button during the click event?  Setting the button enable to false when the button is click will keep it disabled when the file is deleted.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bntDeleteFile.Enabled = false;
}
```

Your "listView1_SelectedIndexChanged" event will enable the button when you select another file.

Comment: The "Form1_Load" event fires prior to the page loading.  You can use this event to set your controls prior to the user seeing the page for the first time.  [Reference Form.Load Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.load?view=netframework-4.7.1)

Comment: @JamesN, read through some of your comments and think I have a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Your solution mostly works; however, it fails to fire sometimes. At this point I can not find a pattern. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the button to disabled when you select a treeview item:

```
    private void TreeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        bntDeleteFile.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that when another directory is selected, you are running a listView1.Items.Clear() (or clearing the bound DataSource), you probably want to run this just before clearing the items:

```
listView1.SelectedItems.Clear();
```

That should clear the selected item, which will trigger the event you want.